# Merge Two csv files with php

Tags: php, csv

i have two csv files: one contracts data and the other containing awarded contracts. I need to combine these two files using common field(contractname) and compute total amount of current awarded contracts. 
Link to csv files:
https://github.com/younginnovations/problem-statements/tree/master/clean-up-contracts-data

I do get desired output bt undefined offset error comes up.
     the code:unset(awards_info[$y][0]); does unsets the data but  'Undefined offset: 0' error occurs..
 similarly the code $list_data[10]!=NULL also shows the same error 
but both are producing desired output.

> ```
> var_dump($awards_info):: produces following:
> array(5) { [0]=> array(6) { [0]=> string(12) "contractName" [1]=> string(12) "contractDate" [2]=> string(14) "completionDate" [3]=> string(7) "awardee" [4]=> string(15) "awardeeLocation" [5]=> string(6) "Amount" } [1]=> array(6) { [0]=> string(15) "Contract-2070-3" [1]=> string(8) "5/9/2014" [2]=> string(9) "8/25/2014" [3]=> string(11) "SK Builders" [4]=> string(5) "Banke" [5]=> string(6) "200000" } [2]=> array(6) { [0]=> string(15) "Contract-2070-5" [1]=> string(9) "3/18/2014" [2]=> string(8) "4/8/2014" [3]=> string(24) "S engineering industries" [4]=> string(9) "Makwanpur" [5]=> string(6) "300000" } [3]=> array(6) { [0]=> string(15) "Contract-2070-9" [1]=> string(8) "3/6/2014" [2]=> string(8) "4/6/2014" [3]=> string(24) "Gourishankar nirman sewa" [4]=> string(8) "Lalitpur" [5]=> string(6) "400000" } [4]=> array(6) { [0]=> string(16) "Contract-2070-10" [1]=> string(8) "2/6/2014" [2]=> string(9) "6/16/2014" [3]=> string(11) "SK Builders" [4]=> string(5) "Banke" [5]=> string(6) "400000" } }
> ```

```
$file_contract=fopen('contracts.csv','r');
$file_awards=fopen('awards.csv','r');
 while(($data=fgetcsv($file_contract))!=FALSE){
$contracts_info[]=$data;
}

while(($data=fgetcsv($file_awards))!=FALSE){
$awards_info[]=$data;
}

$con_count=count($contracts_info);
for($x=0;$x<$con_count;$x++){

    if($x==0){
        unset($awards_info[0][0]);
        $data[$x]=array_merge($contracts_info[0],$awards_info[0]);
        }

    else{
        $check=0;
        $award_count=count($awards_info);
        for($y=1;$y<$award_count;$y++){

            if($awards_info[$y][0]==$contracts_info[$x][0]){

                unset($awards_info[$y][0]);
                $data[$x]=array_merge($contracts_info[$x],$awards_info[$y]);
                $check=1;
                }

            }

            if($check==0){
                $data[$x]=$contracts_info[$x];
                }
        }
}
$final_data=fopen('final.csv','w');
foreach($data as $list_data){
    fputcsv($final_data,$list_data);
    }
    fclose($final_data);
    $c=0;


foreach ($data as $list_data){
    if(($list_data[1]=='Current') && ($list_data[10]!=NULL))
    {
        $c+=$list_data[12];

        }
    }

echo $c;
```

Comment: that array doesn't contain anything, so `[0]` tries to point at something that doesn't exist. start doing `var_dump($whatever)` wherever you get that error, and see what you're really dealing with.

Comment: that array does contain a value... when i echo that array, it does show its value without any errors. Bt when i use unset error is shown on the upper line. (i.e line just before the unset code).

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the content file in the new file, without parsing files :

```
$fp = fopen('final.csv','w');
fwrite($fp, file_get_contents('contracts.csv'));
fwrite($fp, file_get_contents('awards.csv'));
fclose($fp);
echo file_get_contents('final.csv');
```

ok it's a wrong way. So i try to rewrite the loop :

```
for($x=0; $x < count($contracts_info); $x++) {
  $data[$x] = $contracts_info[$x];
  if($x == 0) {
    if(isset($awards_info[$x])) {
      $data[$x] = array_merge($data[$x], $awards_info[$x]);
      unset($awards_info[$x]);
    }
  } else {
    foreach($awards_info as $y => $award_info_datas) {
      if($award_info_datas[0] == $contracts_info[$x][0]) {
        $data[$x] = array_merge($data[$x], $award_info_datas);
        unset($awards_info[$y]);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: i cannot simply get all data from both files and pile them up..
i need to merge data if they have same contractname. so this cannot be a good option for me. anywys all these have already been completed , the only thing bothering me is undefined offset error

Comment: ok, sorry. So can you give us your var_dump of $awards_info and $contracts_info?

Comment: i have edited my question with var_dump($awards_info) output

Comment: that code didn't help either... but i did solve the problem.. :)  i didnt use the isset code before... that helped. thank you anywys